# Python Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

I'm trying to get abbreviations of US states but this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
url='https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states'
web=urlopen(url)
source=BeautifulSoup(web, 'html.parser')
table=source.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter'})
abbs=table.find_all('b')
print(abbs.get_text())
```

returns AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'find_all'. What's the problem of my code?

Comment: `source.find` is returning `None`, which has no attribute `find_all`

Comment: It can't find the element 'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter'.

Comment: It's called 'wikitable sortable' in the HTML.

Comment: @Roy I think my answer will give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments the HTML at the url doesn't have a table with the class

```
'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter'
```

But the class is actually

```
'wikitable sortable'
```

Also once you apply find_all, it returns a list containing all tags so you can't directly apply get_text() to it. You can use list comprehension to strip out the text for each element in the list. Here's the code which will work for your problem

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
url='https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states'
web=urlopen(url)
source=BeautifulSoup(web, 'html.parser')
table=source.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
abbs=table.find_all('b')
values = [ele.text.strip() for ele in abbs]
print(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

I changed the class in source.find to `'wikitable sortable'`. Also, the method `abbs.get_text()` gave me an error, so I just used a generator function to get the text you wanted.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

web = urlopen('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
source = BeautifulSoup(web, 'lxml')
table = source.find(class_='wikitable sortable').find_all('b')
b_arr = '\n'.join([x.text for x in table])
print(b_arr)
```

Partial Output:

```
AL
AK
AZ
AR
CA
CO
```

Comment: There is no need to use string replace, beautiful soup gives you methods to extract text using ele.text.strip()

Answer (score 1):

As [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380110/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-find-all#comment81712479_47380110) suggested,

**source.first()** returns only the first element.

Source code of **first()** method for the reference:

```
def find(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None, **kwargs):
    """Return only the first child of this Tag matching the given criteria."""
    r = None
    l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, 1, **kwargs)
    if l:
        r = l[0]
    return r
findChild = find
```

After extracting table it class name was `wikitable sortable`.
So as per above code, it was returning `None`.

So you may want to change your code as...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states'
web = urlopen(url)
source = BeautifulSoup(web, 'html.parser')

table = source.find('table', class_='wikitable')
abbs = table.find_all('b')

abbs_list = [i.get_text().strip() for i in abbs]
print(abbs_list)
```

I hope it'll answer your question. :)

Comment: Solved the problem. Thanks a lot!